# JPA Filter Properties of Queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, audit

I m thinking the best way to audit and filter JPA Entities Properties and Fields

My Question is think if exists an interface or thing that filter the results

Example i have a User with Admin role and another User with Seller role, both can make queries, but not both can read and write the all properties. To writes filter i thinking make a interceptor with Thread attributes to know the role of current Thread. but in the query i can not know what is the property to filter.

Example

```
EntityManager em = ...
Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT AVG(x.price) FROM Magazine x");
Number result = (Number) q.getSingleResult ();
```

To interceptor the result of Method is a Integer but how to a know what is the entity and what is the property to read.

for the user with seller role the price must shows
But for the user with admin role the price must be NULL (suppose that the admin can not see the prices)

Exist some with JPA or Hibernate to do this? i make a question to air.. to listen some idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly for the the first problem you can use TypedQuery. Authorisation is a different problem and you should handle it somewhere else (not in DB code)

Comment: This is my question.. i need create a base to another programmers making that but.. where is the place to remove the properties unauthorized to read, if after that the method returns the value the value is out of my control.

Comment: I guess you could have implemented Spring Security for example